# populate a json file

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, seeding

I'm trying to populate a json file with some fake seed data for a User db collection:
Here is how i'm writing to the json file:
[Generate json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8IRB.png)

Here is what I get as output in the User.json file:
[User.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udEwa.png)

But this is what I get if I console.log(people) after the for loop:

```
[ { f_name: 'Destin',
    l_name: 'Halvorson',
    username: 'Mustafa.Nitzsche',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Giovani',
    l_name: 'Weber',
    username: 'Jodie.Frami25',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Zion',
    l_name: 'Hermann',
    username: 'Brain.Deckow',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Walker',
    l_name: 'Donnelly',
    username: 'Berniece14',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Stanton',
    l_name: 'Rau',
    username: 'Alysha18',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Alexandrea',
    l_name: 'Emard',
    username: 'Juvenal9',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Elta',
    l_name: 'Bailey',
    username: 'Foster.Mann',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Noemie',
    l_name: 'Zboncak',
    username: 'Guillermo45',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Elva',
    l_name: 'Weissnat',
    username: 'Willie_Koss',
    password: 'password' },
  { f_name: 'Danny',
    l_name: 'Dickinson',
    username: 'Melyna_Herman87',
    password: 'password' } ]
```

This btw is exactly what I want

I'm just curious about why it reverts back to each element being an "object"?

Any tips or answers would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
`JSON.stringify(object, replacer, space);`

For your case I would:
`JSON.stringify(people, null, '\t');`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Haha! the "\t" formats it perfectly, I didn't know what that was doing; very cool! Thanks for your help